# Javac doesn't create native .c file from .java. JNI

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, javac

I tried to create `.c` and `.h` files from my class and got a really strange problem. While javah creates a `.h` file from my `.java` file perfectly - javac doesn't create a `.c` file, instead it creates `.class` file with no errors in logs!

Java source:

```
package com.iiordanov.bVNC;

//import java.io.IOException;

public class NativeCalls {
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary("start-spice-xml");
    }
   public native static  String[] getPortAndPassword(String server, String name);//  throws IOException;
}
```

I am currently running on Fedora. When I try to run from src folder:

```
javac com/iiordanov/bVNC/NativeCalls.java
```

it creates NativeCalls.class, but I need `.c` style class. On the other hand,

```
javah -jni com.iiordanov.bVNC.NativeCalls
```

works perfectly and creates `com_iiordanov_bVNC_NativeCalls.h`.

How can I generate a `.c` file from my Java source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javac is not meant to create C files. It's a Java compiler - source to bytecode.

If you want a C file with empty implementations for your native functions, pass the `-stubs` option to `javah`.

Comment: Oh fk i was unattentive ((( Didn't see they use it only to compile java file not automaticly creating( like javah does - thnx Dude!!)) Spasibo)))

Comment: Here at SO, we say thanks by accepting the answer :)

Comment: I've been doing some experimental bindings to Java myself (though I don't normally use Java), didn't know about the `-stubs` option. Handy. Upvoted.